# JavaScript not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a simple page that you can see here :http://jsfiddle.net/NdhnY/

For some unknown reason the javascript doesn't execute, and i can't figure out why.
The scripts ARE found (i checked on firebug). I also tried adding type="text/javascript", but no result.

Can you help me please ? Thank you.

EDIT: i'll paste a piece of code since this is mandatory :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Void Museum</title>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascrpt" src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascrpt" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <h1 id="tb-logo">Void Museum</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <input id="tb-btn-home" title="Home" type="button">
                        <p>Home</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <input id="tb-btn-account" title="Account" type="button">
                        <p>Account</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <input id="tb-btn-about" title="About" type="button">
                        <p>About</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <input id="tb-btn-fullscreen" title="Enable fullscreen" type="button">
                        <p>Full screen</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be .... Javascript is disabled in your Browser...

Comment: Your Fiddle is failing because you have not included jQuery (via the drop-down on the left).

Comment: You don't load jQuery properly, your `src` of the `<script>` tag is pointing to a non-existing location: `<script src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>`. You can include jQuery on JSFiddle on the left side under *Frameworks & Extensions*. `main.js` can also not be found. Check your console.

Comment: Okay for the fiddle, but why would it fail without the fiddle when i've corrected the colon mistake, used $(function(){}), when jQuery IS found, and when i add an alart at the first line of the script ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NdhnY/5/ - The Fix is here...

Comment: Well i've removed the type="text/javascript" and for some reason it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem :

```
<script type="text/javascrpt" src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascrpt" src="main.js"></script>
```

javascript was mispelled.

Comment: This was one of many problems your code had.
1. Incorrect calling of the document.ready for the version of jQuery you had.
2. Using a : instead of an ; on the line ending
3. misnaming the type tag - which shouldnt be used anyways as it optional - all browsers know that the default script is JS since netscape 2

Comment: Which i would have found if the script had executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your document.ready is incorrect check it out here:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Code to fix:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $(function() {alert(0); //in jQuery this is equivalent to $( document ).ready( handler )

        $( '#tb-btn-fullscreen' ).on( 'click', function() {

            var docElm = document.documentElement;

            if( docElm.requestFullscreen )
            {
                docElm.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if( docElm.mozRequestFullScreen )
            {
                docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if( docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen )
            {
                docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
        });

    }); // HERE YOU HAD A : and not a ;

})( jQuery );
```

From jQuery:

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of
>   jQuery 1.8. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the
>   ready event has already fired and you try to .on( "ready" ) the bound
>   handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are
>   executed after any bound by the other three methods above.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/NdhnY/5/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but an alert at the beginning of the script doesn't work either.

Answer (score -2):

1) `(function( $ ) {`

2)   `$( document ).on( 'ready', function() {`

Meaning of 1 and 2 is same so use only one soemthing like

```
(function( $ ) {

  alert(0);
   .....
   .....
})( jQuery );
```

In [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NdhnY/3/) There is being alerted.

Comment: actually no... this is incorrect... He is wrapping it in an IIFE and passing jQuery as a param.

Comment: Please tell what is incorrect, what I am telling to OP, I am not talking about passing parameter.

Comment: The first one has nothing to do with the second one. The first one like I said is wrapping the function in an IIFE so it will execute when the JS is loaded. Then there is a handler for the second one that will fire when the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Sten Muchow Have a closer look at the first line, i'm using `(function( $ ) {` (module pattern), not `$(function() {`

Comment: That is what i said.. IIFE loading jQuery. Check out the example I put at the top... http://jsfiddle.net/NdhnY/5/

Comment: How would `(function( $ ) { })( jQuery );` load anything ? :/

Comment: I never said it would load anything - I said it will fire on page load passing jQuery as a param to the inner function - did u read what i wrote?

Comment: It fires when the script is executed, it's not a callback, it's a closure that is called right after being defined. I could do that without jQuery.

Comment: I see how it could be misunderstood from my above comment. I simply meant that it will be passed into closure so jQuery is available aka...loaded...